# Creating multiple instances of wx.App - is it ok?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, wxpython

so I need to implement a following scenario:
- Several tasks are running simultaneously as processes.
- Each task should display a progress bar with a "Cancel" button, clicking on which should terminate it.

To achieve responsive GUI, I run the task for each process in a separate thread, and it seems that I need to create a separate `wx.App` for each process as well, otherwise the thread seems to be not running. This setup works fine, however:

a) I am not sure whether multiple `wx.App`'s is a good idea or

b) If there is a better way of achieving my goal.

MWE below (note: in this sample code I could have used `Update` method of `wx.ProgressDialog` to identify whether the "Cancel" button has been pressed, but can't do so for my real application).

```
import wx, multiprocessing, time, psutil
from multiprocessing import Queue
from threading import Thread
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub as Publisher

#runs the task
def task_runner(q):
    pid = multiprocessing.current_process().pid
    q.put(pid)

    while True:
        print("Process Running")
        time.sleep(1)
        wx.CallAfter(Publisher.sendMessage, "update") #call to update the bar

class TestPanel():

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.q = Queue()
        self.count=0
        max = 80

        # dialog to see progress and cancel the task
        self.dlg = wx.GenericProgressDialog(name,
                               "An informative message",
                               maximum = max,
                               parent=None,
                               style = wx.PD_CAN_ABORT
                                | wx.PD_APP_MODAL
                                | wx.PD_ELAPSED_TIME
                                )

        #set listener to dialog's "Cancel" button
        for child in self.dlg.GetChildren():
            if isinstance(child, wx.Button):
                cancel_function = lambda evt, parent=self.dlg: self.onClose(evt, parent)
                child.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, cancel_function)

        #subscribe to update the progress bar from the thread
        Publisher.subscribe(self.updateProgress, "update")


        # start thread which runs some task
        p = Thread(target=task_runner, args=(self.q,))
        p.start()


    #updates the progress bar
    def updateProgress(self):
        print("updating progress")
        self.count=self.count+10
        self.dlg.Update(self.count)

    #kills the process
    def kill(self, proc_pid):
            process = psutil.Process(proc_pid)
            for proc in process.children(recursive=True):
                proc.kill()
            process.kill()

    #closing the dialog event
    def onClose(self, event, dialog):
        """"""
        print "Closing dialog!"
        pid = self.q.get()
        self.kill(pid)
        dialog.Destroy()

# run process, each process creates its own wx.App
def runProcess(name):
    app = wx.App(False)
    TestPanel(name)
    app.MainLoop()


# worker class to use for multiprocessing pool
class Worker():
    def __call__(self, name):
        return runProcess(name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    items=['Bar1', 'Bar2']
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2)
    result = pool.map(Worker(), items) #create two processes
    pool.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, having more than one `wx.App` in a single process is not a good idea.  Even creating a new one after the prior is finished can sometimes be problematic.

However since you are using `multiprocess` it is not quite the same.  Unless I'm missing something, each OS process does have just one `wx.App` in your case, and since the parent process is not creating a `wx.App` then they are not trying to inherit that one (which would likely cause even more problems.)

Comment: Thanks for the input. Actually for my real application (not the code here), parent process **does** create a `wx.App` - I will report any issues arising. So far however my problem is the termination of the processes - they stop running when user clicks "Cancel" but python tasks still keep running in background. I might have to ask about this in a separate question.