# How to Properly Handle Multiple Calls to wx.App() using wxPython Phoenix

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, wxpython

I am trying to troubleshoot/de-bug an issue I came across with my application using wxPython 4.0.7.

I re-wrote my entire program that was functioning with Python 2.7 and wxPython 2.8 on a Windows 7 32-bit system to now work with 64 bit Python 3.7.4 and wxPython 4.0.7 on a 64 bit Windows 10 system.

The problem I am having is that my program requires that it iterate multiple times based on the number of loops specified by the user, and it calls an instance of `wx.App()` from two different python scripts utilized.

I have read that calling multiple instances of `wx.App()` is a "no-no" (see [creating multiple instances of wx.App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41154808/creating-multiple-instances-of-wx-app-is-it-ok))

Clearly this is a problem with this version of wxPython as my application crashes after the first iteration now, when it worked fine before.

Okay, so I understand this now, but I am not certain what the "fix" is for my particular issue.

The basic outline of my application is this:
A "runner.py" script is launched which contains the main `wx.frame()` gui and the following code is appended to the end of the script:

```
app = wx.App()
frame = Runner(parent=None, foo=Foo)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

When the user clicks on the "execute" button in the wxPython GUI, I have a progress dialog that initiates using this code:

```
pd = wx.ProgressDialog(title = "Runner.py", message= "Starting Model", parent=self, style=wx.PD_AUTO_HIDE | wx.PD_SMOOTH | wx.PD_CAN_ABORT )
pd.Update(15)
```

The runner.py script executes a "for loop" that does a bunch of stuff (actually reads in some inputs from R scripts) and then once it's done, it opens up a second python script ("looping.py") and iterates through a set of processes based on the number of loops the user specifies in the GUI launched from runner.py.

As the user needs to visually see what loop process the model run is going through, I have inside this second "looping.py" script, yet another instance of `wx.App()` that calls up another `wx.ProgressDialog()`, And the script looks like this:

```
#Progress Bar to user to start model
app = wx.App()
pd = wx.ProgressDialog("looping.py", "Setup Iteration", parent=None, style=wx.PD_AUTO_HIDE | wx.PD_SMOOTH |  wx.PD_CAN_ABORT )
pd.Update(15)
```

My specific question is this:  **How do I initiate the `wx.ProgressDialog()` successfully within the "looping.py" script without it crashing my application past the first iteration?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably have to sub-class `wx.ProgressDialog`, arguably it may be easier to write your own progress bar display.
Something like this, may give you some ideas.
I've included the ability to run multiple threads doing different things, with `pause` and `stop` buttons. The main frame has a button to test whether the Gui is still active, whilst running the threads.
Updates from the thread are driven by an `event`
You may wish to reduce or increase its options.

```
import time
import wx
from threading import Thread
import wx.lib.newevent
progress_event, EVT_PROGRESS_EVENT = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Main Frame', size=(400,400))
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.text_count = 0
        self.parent=parent
        self.btn_start = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, label='Start Long running process', size=(180,30), pos=(10,10))
        btn_test = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, label='Is the GUI still active?', size=(180,30), pos=(10,50))
        self.txt = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, style= wx.TE_MULTILINE, pos=(10,90),size=(300,100))

        self.btn_start.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Start_Process)
        btn_test.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.ActiveText)

    def Start_Process(self, event):
        process1 = ProcessingFrame(title='Threaded Task 1', parent=self, job_no=1)
        process2 = ProcessingFrame(title='Threaded Task 2', parent=self, job_no=2)
        self.btn_start.Enable(False)

    def ActiveText(self,event):
        self.text_count += 1
        txt = "Gui is still active " + str(self.text_count)+"\n"
        self.txt.write(txt)

class ProcessingFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, title, parent=None,job_no=1):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=parent, title=title, size=(400,400))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.parent = parent
        self.job_no = job_no
        self.btn = wx.Button(panel,label='Stop processing', size=(200,30), pos=(10,10))
        self.btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnExit)
        self.btn_pause = wx.Button(panel,label='Pause processing', size=(200,30), pos=(10,50))
        self.btn_pause.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnPause)
        self.progress = wx.Gauge(panel,size=(200,10), pos=(10,90), range=60)
        self.process = wx.TextCtrl(panel,size = (200,250), pos=(10,120), style = wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        #Bind to the progress event issued by the thread
        self.Bind(EVT_PROGRESS_EVENT, self.OnProgress)
        #Bind to Exit on frame close
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnExit)
        self.Show()

        self.mythread = TestThread(self)

    def OnProgress(self, event):
        self.progress.SetValue(event.count)
        self.process.write(event.process+"\n")
        self.Refresh()
        if event.count >= 60:
            self.OnExit(None)

    def OnExit(self, event):
        if self.mythread.isAlive():
            self.mythread.terminate() # Shutdown the thread
            self.mythread.join() # Wait for it to finish
            self.parent.btn_start.Enable(True)
        self.Destroy()

    def OnPause(self, event):
        if self.mythread.isAlive():
            self.mythread.pause() # Pause the thread

class TestThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self,parent_target):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.target = parent_target
        self.stopthread = False
        self.process = 1 # Testing only - mock process id
        self.start()    # start the thread

    def run(self):
        # A selectable test loop that will run for 60 loops then terminate
        if self.target.job_no == 1:
            self.run1()
        else:
            self.run2()

    def run1(self):
        curr_loop = 0
        while self.stopthread != True:
            if self.stopthread == "Pause":
                time.sleep(1)
                continue
            curr_loop += 1
            self.process += 10 # Testing only - mock process id
            if curr_loop <= 60: # Update progress bar
                time.sleep(1.0)
                evt = progress_event(count=curr_loop,process="Envoking process "+str(self.process))
                #Send back current count for the progress bar
                try:
                    wx.PostEvent(self.target, evt)
                except: # The parent frame has probably been destroyed
                    self.terminate()
        self.terminate()

    def run2(self):
        curr_loop = 0
        while self.stopthread != True:
            if self.stopthread == "Pause":
                time.sleep(1)
                continue
            curr_loop += 1
            self.process += 100 # Testing only - mock process id
            if curr_loop <= 60: # Update progress bar
                time.sleep(1.0)
                evt = progress_event(count=curr_loop,process="Checking process"+str(self.process))
                #Send back current count for the progress bar
                try:
                    wx.PostEvent(self.target, evt)
                except: # The parent frame has probably been destroyed
                    self.terminate()
        self.terminate()

    def terminate(self):
        self.stopthread = True

    def pause(self):
        if self.stopthread == "Pause":
            self.stopthread = False
            self.target.btn_pause.SetLabel('Pause processing')
        else:
            self.stopthread = "Pause"
            self.target.btn_pause.SetLabel('Continue processing')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: I am accepting your answer as the most helpful in pointing me in the direction of resolving this issue. The start/stop loop was very useful because I have 9 loops to iterate over in my case and this helped me visualize the multi-threading process better.  Your efforts are much appreciated.